# Declaration of 'FIRStorageHandle' must be imported from module 'FirebaseStorage.FIRStorageTypedefs' before it is required

Tags: ios, flutter

```
Modules Issue (Xcode): Declaration of 'FIRStorageHandle' must be imported from module 'FirebaseStorage.FIRStorageTypedefs' before it is required
```

/Users/builder/programs/flutter_3_0_5/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_storage-8.1.3/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseStoragePlugin.m:410:14

I am trying to build flutter ios build using codemagic but it throws error. Please anyone help  me.

Answer (score 1):

For me this started when upgrading XCode. I made sure Firebase extensions were all using same SDK (9.5.0) and ran this from the root of the project:

```
flutter clean && flutter pub get && flutter pub upgrade && cd ios/ && pod install --repo-update
```

Took some time, but now everything is fresh and working again

Answer (score 0):

you can check the xCode version, in my case I had to upgrade to the latest available Xcode 13.3.x

Comment: My xcode has latest version installed. I tried to figure out problem from many days but still no result. I also try to upgrade firebase storage package but no result.

Comment: also tried removing ios/Podfile.lock and updating firebase_storage firebase_core dependencies,

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading xCode didn't solve this for me. I had to upgrade firebase_storage to:
firebase_storage: ^10.3.7
Clean and rebuild the project and this fixed it for me.